# Error 405 using axios post request in react native

Tags: axios, react-native, expo

I'm making an post request using axios in my expo react native app but I don't know why my post request is returning error

> Request failed with status code 405

When I check my API on postman so it shows me the expected result. I attached the method which hits `onPress` on button. Kindly check and provide me a solution.

```
async onSubmit(ref) {
        if (ref.state.emailID && ref.state.password) {
            this.showLoader();
            await axios.post('http://apiurl.com/api/user/Userlogin?emailID=' + ref.state.emailID + '&password=' + ref.state.password,
                { emailID: ref.state.emailID, password: ref.state.password },
                { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log('Innnn');
                    this.hideLoader();
                    console.log("response data: ", response.data);
                }).catch(err => {
                    this.hideLoader();
                    console.log("error: ", err.message);
                })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you attaching emailId and password in your request URL? Can you attach screenshot of what you are doing in postman and what response you are getting (in your question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing a very silly mistake, the request has been changed from `post` to `get`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so there are multiple things which are wrong in you code.

To answer your question at start, I would suggest you to add `withCredentials: true}`

Try adding `{withCredentials: true}` in your axios request.

Second, with **async and await**, you don't need to use .then and catch (rather use `try..catch`)

```
async onSubmit(ref) {
    if (ref.state.emailID && ref.state.password) {
    try {
       this.showLoader();
         const networkReq = await axios.post('http://apiurl.com/api/user/Userlogin?emailID=' + ref.state.emailID + '&password=' + ref.state.password,
          {withCredentials: true},
         { emailID: ref.state.emailID, password: ref.state.password },
         { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
       this.hideLoader();
       console.log(networkReq.data) 
    } catch (error) {
      this.hideLoader();
      console.log("error: ", err.message);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: @ZaInKhAn log your request, I would typically create `payload` which I would pass to `axios.create`. There could be something wrong with your request. Log parameters you are passing and make sure there isn't undefined and you are passing the correct type

Comment: Yes I'm sure that there is no undefined object.

Comment: The error is still there after updating my code according to your suggestion

Comment: Why are you attaching emailId and password in your request URL? Can you attach screenshot of what you are doing in postman and what response you are getting (in your question)?

Comment: Thank you so much @iRohitBhatia. I was doing a very silly mistake my api developer has changed the api request from post to get. Now it's working fine thank you much again for your help.